# complex and nested DOM traversing confusion

Tags: html, dom, xpath

[image]

I want to get the span value (Salary vs age) but so far I'm stuck at the td part. I wrote

`$x("//tr/td[@class='row1']")` but it didn't select the 3rd td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the xpath should be

```
//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]//span[1]
```

Comment: the 3 means after class = row1 found it skip 3 step forward?

Comment: no, it is a predicate for `td`. It means the third `td`.

Comment: why @class='row1' is not enough to select the element? and need to use [3]?

Comment: because the first and second `td`s also has `@class='row1'`.

Comment: thx man, I did not see that. How about the //span[1] ? the span is within td, why not use / instead of //?

Comment: the `//` means descendant, the `/` means child